# What are the alternatives to catchfilebetweentags?

Tags: verbatim, input, catchfile

I want to be able to have files `chapter1.tex`, `chapter2.tex`, etc. (with preambles) that can compile on their own and a file `allChapters.tex` that gather the actual contents of the chapters.

So far, I have been able to do this with the package `catchfilebetweentags`.

But, it seems that the package `catchfilebetweentags` intefers with the package `verbatim`.

Is there an alternative to catchfilebetweentags to achieve my initial goal?

Comment: I would simply have a file for each chapter rather than rely on delicate packaegs matching subsections of your main file. if the ody of chapter2 is `\include` into your main document have a file chap2.tex that has a preamble then includes the same file.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure to understand your idea. Could you more precise/explicit (maybe in an answer)? My conclusion so far is that I should create an external script.

Comment: I am not sure what you need, why do you need more than the standard `\include` mechanism that is designed to allow individual chapters to be processed separately

Comment: I feel it is not convenient at all when the file that I compile is not the file where I write the content.

Comment: aren't most reasonable sized documents spread over multiple files? most people writing a document which is big enough to have chapters has at least one file per chapter I would have thought. the filename to pass to latex is just a detail like whether --shell-escape is needed or whether to use biber or bibtex I am very surprised by your comment, but everyone has different preferences.

Comment: My coauthor feels the same. I think it depends also on how you compile your LaTeX files (via an editor or in a terminal), your unix culture, etc. Having to switch files before compiling is quite annoying I feel. I use TeXShop on MacOS.

Comment: I don't know texshop but any reasonable editor would allow you to specify a master file so editing chapter1.tex you could run latex on main.tex with a key shortcut without having to bring main.tex into the editor (the editor I use (emacs) has had that feature since the 1980s)

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle: I didn't it existed!! I've just looked and TeXShop has this feature.  This will help me a lot.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Since it is your suggestion that finally helped me, you can make it an answer if you want, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3):

The two packages I know of that can do that are the `subfiles` package and the `standalone` package. My favorite is subfiles, but each file uses the main preamble, so if you want individual preambles for each, you probably want `standalone`. I will describe both.

### The standalone package

With this package, each and every file in the project must be able to work individually, hence its name "standalone." It has a default command for inserting the files, `\input{}`, but it requres that each file is in the same directory, which quickly becomes unruly, so I strongly reccomend you use the `import` package as well. Below is an example of syntax, it is not a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
    
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}
    
\begin{document}
    
Hi, this is not a MWE, just an example of the syntax the standalone package uses.
I did that because it requres multiple files.
    
\import{directory}{filename}
    
\end{document}
```

### The subfiles package

In this package, which I prefer to `standalone`, the documents are not independant of each other. The subfiles use the main document's preamble. This package has one catch: the main file must be named `main.tex`, and if you want to nest subfiles, each nested main file must also be called `main.tex`, which can get confusing if you dont name your directories appropriately. Below is an example of syntax, it is not a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}

Hi, this is not a MWE, just an example of the syntax the subfiles package uses.
I did that because it requires multiple files.

\subfile{directory/filename}

Note that each subfile must start with \documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}.
If you nest subfiles, add a .. to the begining of the argument for each level of nesting.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you structure your document chapter-wise, then use `\include` and `\includeonly`. You will compile always `main.tex`, but can control via `\includeonly`, which chapters are actually typeset. In this solution, there is only one preamble (in `main.tex`) which is used for all runs.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\includeonly{chapter1,chapter4}
% ... preamble with definitions and \usepackages
\begin{document}
\include{chapter1}% will be included 
\include{chapter2}% will be skipped
\include{chapter3}% will be skipped
\include{chapter4}% will be included
\end{document}

%chapter1.tex
\chapter{My first chapter}
Text of first chapter.

%chapter2.tex
\chapter{My second chapter}
Text of second chapter.

% and so on ...
```

**Solution proposed by David Carlisle**

```
% allChapters.tex
\documentclass{...}
% ... preamble for allChapters
\begin{document}
\input{chapter1}
\input{chapter2}
\input{chapter3)
\end{document}

% chap1.tex typesets only chapter1.tex
\documentclass{...}
% ... preamble for chapter1.tex
\begin{document}
\input{chapter1}
\end{document}
```

**David's solution with shared preamble**

```
% mypreamble.tex
% ... all the definitions and \usepackages

% allChapters.tex
\documentclass{...}
\input{mypreamble} % load the common preamble
\begin{document}
\input{chapter1}
\input{chapter2}
\input{chapter3)
\end{document}

% chap1.tex typesets only chapter1.tex
\documentclass{...}
\input{mypreamble} % load the common preamble
\begin{document}
\input{chapter1}
\end{document}
```

**What to do when the files reside in different directories, when the chapter files have further subfiles etc.**

In this case use the answer of @Will and use `standalone` or `subfiles`.